# MySQLInstance Configuration

Tags: mysql

i am using this line to configure MySQL 5.1

MySQLInstanceConfig.exe -i -q -lmysql_config.log ServerType=SERVER DatabaseType=MIXED ConnectionUsage=DSS Port=3306 AddBinToPath=yes ConnectionCount=10 SkipNetworking=no StrictMode=no RootPassword=password

it configures the server and the service is started fine, but the StrictMode is enabled even though i am disabling it in the configuration above...

if i look at my.ini i find

Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

which i think is not supposed to be there...

am doing anything wrong? i am using the parameter wrong?

Vladimir,

Answer (score 1):

By using the my.ini mode of "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", you are saying to use strict mode for transactional engines and, if possible, for nontransactional engines.

If you take that out, you should be ok.

Comment: Hi,

i am not writing these values into the my.ini files, i don't understand how its being written when in the Instance Configuration i am setting the StrictMode to no...

its like the configuration is ignoring the StrictMode Parameter...

Please advise...

Thanks for the reply

Vladimir.

Comment: Vladimir, think of it as a conflict.  In the command line you're telling it to not use strict.  In the my.ini you are telling it to use strict.

It's ignoring the strictmode parameter...because you're telling it to use strict mode by having STRICT_TRANS_TABLES.

Comment: Hi, 

i have not modified the my.ini files, i believe the my.ini file is created with the options you specify in the MySQLConfigInstance (or its supposed to). given a mchine that has never seen MySQL, i run the configuration as mentioned, but i still get the same results...

maybe i should change the my.ini myself but that just sound wrong...